# DEFROUTE usage in RHEL 7

Tags: linux, ifconfig

I am stuck with this configuration here after commenting the `DEFRROUTE` line I get the `ip r` output like this. Does it really works with `DEFRROUTE=no` when uncommented.

```
[root@vm1 ~]# ip r
default via 192.168.5.1 dev eth0  proto static  metric 100
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth2  proto static  metric 101    
169.24.0.0/17 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 169.24.0.5  metric 100
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth2  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.3  metric 100
192.168.5.0/28 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.5.10  metric 100


[root@vm1 ~]# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth2
DEVICE=eth2
BOOTPROTO=static
ONBOOT=yes
USERCTL=no
TYPE=Ethernet
IPADDR=192.168.1.3
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
GATEWAY=192.168.1.1
#DEFRROUTE=no

[root@vm1 ~]# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
DEVICE=eth0
BOOTPROTO=static
ONBOOT=yes
USERCTL=no
TYPE=Ethernet
IPADDR=192.168.5.10
NETMASK=255.255.255.240
GATEWAY=192.168.5.1
#DEFRROUTE=yes

[root@vm1 ~]# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1
DEVICE=eth1
BOOTPROTO=static
ONBOOT=yes
USERCTL=no
TYPE=Ethernet
IPADDR=169.24.0.5
NETMASK=255.255.128.0
#DEFRROUTE=no
```

When I uncomment the DEFRROUTE I get this below output without route

```
[root@vm1 ~]# ip r
169.24.0.0/17 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 169.24.0.5  metric 100
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth2  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.3  metric 100
192.168.5.0/28 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.5.10  metric 100
```

As @artem suggested via the link, below is the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: assume that u have two lan card you have provide ip,subnet and gateway in both lan card, now system used both lan card to reach the destination when you put "DEFROUTE=yes" on lan card one then system always use lan card one on priority to reach every destination..

Answer (score 1):

Try changing it to `DEFROUTE` as opposed to `DEFRROUTE`.

Comment: But why is that needed, could you provide some more information on that.

Comment: Well, because this is merely right syntax. Try searching for it in CentOS/RHEL docs. For example, [link](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-networkscripts-interfaces.html)

Comment: See the edited question. its not mentioned anywhere in the link.

Answer (score 0):

`DEFROUTE` parameter suitable in `ppp` interface configuration, or may be for `BOOTPROTO=dhcp`.

- For Ethernet where you want to have the Default Route set the GATEWAY parameter.
- For Ethernet where You want **not** to have Dafault Route omit (or comment) GATEWAY parameter.